# What is Bootstrap object in magento2?

Tags: magento2

What is the bootstrap object?
How Magento initializes an application using the Bootstrap object.

Answer (score 1):

Although its a theory question i consider this will be most important before developing Magento applications.

As predecessor entry point in Magento 2 is also index.php.

It includes bootstrap then creates the app from the bootstrap object and finally calls run function of bootstrap.

**Bootstrap**

Bootstrap provides the environment for running Magento app. 
It checks PHP version, sets default error reporting, defines the base path, initializes and populate autoloader (mapping from a namespace prefix to directories to search in for the corresponding class).

**Initialization of code**

- Checks PHP version (if PHP version is  less than 5.5.0 then shows an error message and exit execution.)
- Sets default error reporting to “E_ALL”
- Define the base path of the root directory.
- Initialize autoloader
- Sets the status of profiler
- Sets default time zone to “UTC”

**Initialize / Create App**

- Initialize object manager
- Get main configuration array from /app/etc/config.php

**Run App**

- Initialize error handler
- Initialize object manager if not initialized till now.
- Check maintenance mode is on or not if on then show maintenance page.
- Check installation has completed or not if not then redirect it to /setup/index.php

**Launch**

- Get/Set area code

  - Firstly it gets area code frontend or adminhtml
  - Then sets area code
- Load config and configure

  - It loads configuration according to area
- Get front controller instance and call the dispatch function for routing

Answer (score 0):

In general, the bootstrap object uses the following algorithm to run the Magento application:

1. Initializes the error handler.
2. Creates the object manager and basic shared services that are used everywhere and are affected by the environment. The environment parameters are injected properly into these objects.
3. Asserts that maintenance mode is not enabled; otherwise, terminates.
4. Asserts that the Magento application is installed; otherwise, terminates.
   Starts the Magento application.

For more info, please [click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/bootstrap/magento-bootstrap.html)